# A fundamental question about cosets

Tags: group-theory

I have pretty fundamental question about cosets in group theory:

Lets say we have a group $G$,subgroup $H\le G$,and group $S$ such that $S=G/H$.

So the question is,why if $H=G$ (which means $S=G/G$) means that $S=1$ ("The trivial group",$\{e\}$).

As I understand - $S=G/G=\{g_1g_2|g_1,g_2\in G\}=G$.

Comment: First of all, note that $S = G/H$ is not a group in general. It can be equipped with a natural group structure in the case that $H$ is normal. Regarding your question, ask yourself, what are the elements of $G/H$ and when are two elements in $G/H$ equal? When you have understood this, note that any two elements of $G/G$ are equal, so it is a singleton set.

Comment: You seem to have written up the definition of $GG$ rather than of $G/G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking cosets of $G$. Think about what this means. A coset $xG$ of $G$ would be a set of the form $\{xg : g \in G\}$. In words, we take an element $x$ of $G$ and multiply it by all other elements in $G$, including itself. But by the definition of a group, this must be closed under the binary operation of $G$. Thus, there are no other elements $y \in G$ that we can use to generate additional cosets. The quotient group $G/G$ is then a single coset that is isomorphic to the trivial group. You can think of the quotient as setting all the elements in $G$ equal to each other. In particular, all elements $g \in G$ are now equivalent to the identity $e \in G$.

Also note: In your question, you only made mention of a subgroup of $G$. However, this is not enough to form a quotient group. The subgroup must be a **normal** subgroup of $G$. This does two important things. It first sets left and right cosets equal to each other. Namely, $xN$ = $Nx$ for any normal subgroup $N \lhd G$. In turn, setting left and right cosets equal to each other allows us to define a well-defined operation on the new quotient group $G/N$, $aN \cdot bN = (ab)N.$

Comment: So basically when looking at the group $G/G$ then $G$ is like the "unit coset"?

Comment: @ChikChak Exactly, it is the only coset in $G/G$, meaning it must act like the identity in $G/G$. This follows from the fact that all one-element groups are isomorphic to the trivial group.